# Set JomSocial as root path in Joomla 3.4

Tags: components, joomla3.0, jomsocial

I installed JomSocial as a component in my Joomla 3.4 deployment. whenever I access this component, the URL is like `http://example.com/jomsocial/profile`. How can I make it default/main/dominating component, which has URL like:
`http://example.com/profile`
`http://example.com/inbox`
and `http://example.com/` pointing to JomSocial homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Manage Extensions page in JoomSEF, open the JomSocial extension parameters, and on the Common tab you can either disable this by setting "Show Menu Title" to "No" or use the "Custom Menu Title" field to set your own.

Comment: I looked up and found that JoomSEF is another extension, do I have to install it first?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way myself:
1. Go to admin page > `Menus`
2. Click on link `Home`
3. Click button `Select` > chose `Home` beneath tree `Community`
4. Save